# HomebrewでインストールしたPHPのインストール先とphp.iniの場所を確認するには？

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

mac OS(Sierra)にHomebrewを使用してphpをインストールしました。

php.iniを編集したいのですが、その場所がどこにあるのかわかりません。
ついでに、phpの本体が入っているフォルダの場所も教えてください。
見つけ方なども。

よろしくお願いします。

**追記**

```
$ php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

このコマンドで、iniファイルの場所はわかりました。

でも、phpのインストールされているフォルダーがどこなのかわかりません。
その見つけ方を教えてください。

Comment: macユーザーでないので確認できないのですが、たとえば`$ php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"`とかではどうでしょうか。[PHP: Options - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)

Comment: おなじく `php --ini` を試してみたらどうでしょうか

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。質問内容に追加で書きました。まだ、phpのインストールされたフォルダーがどこなのかわかりません

Comment: `where php` でどうでしょうか。 `Loaded Configuration File`と異なるということですか？

Comment: where: command not found
とターミナルに出ます。
phpのインストールされたディレクトリは、/etcの中にはありませんでした。iniファイルのphp.ini.defaultはありましたので、これを使ってiniファイルを作りました。

Comment: where ではなくて which ではないでしょうか。もしくは `type php` とか。

Comment: which php とすると、phpのファイルが/usr/bin/phpにあると出ましたのでそこをみると、そのファイルがありました。でも、phpというフォルダはありませんでした。Macでphpをインストールすると、どういうふうにインストールされるのか・・・わかりません。

Comment: どういう状態を想定されているのかよくわからないのですが、通常は、php.iniを置くフォルダと、phpの実行ファイルがあるフォルダ（=phpのインストールされているフォルダ？）は同じフォルダではないです（OSや使う開発ツールによってはそうなのかもしれませんが）。homebrewでインストールしたのを使いたいらしいことと、phpというフォルダを探してるらしい、ということから考えると、探してるフォルダは`/usr/local/etc/php/`なのかな？と思いますが（推測）。

Comment: コメントでディスカッションしないでください。追加の疑問がある場合は質問を追記するか別の質問として投稿してください。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

MacなどUnix系統のOSで特定のコマンド(実行ファイル)の場所を探すときは`which`コマンドを用います。

`which php`で`php`と入力した時に使われる優先度が最も高い実行ファイルが表示されます。
同一名の実行ファイルが複数あるときは`which -a php`ですべて表示されます。

また`brew`の`php`のパッケージに関する情報は`brew info php`で見れますので
そのなかに以下のような記述がありました。
こちらの方法でも`php.ini`の場所を見つけることができます。

> The php.ini and php-fpm.ini file can be found in:
>       /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/

またファイルが複数箇所に分散して置かれているのはUnix系列のOSで採用されている`Filesystem Hierarchy Standard`に基づいています。

ディストリビューションごとに規則が微妙に違っていてそれらをすべて覚えるのは大変なので、
まずはそういう決まり事があるということだけ記憶しておくと良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Homebrewの環境であれば、`which`コマンドの代わりに`brew ls <PACKAGE>`で確認するのもよさそうです。

```
$ brew ls <PACKAGE>
```

参考:
[List all files in a homebrew package - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19010784)